# Getting exception "No module named 'airflow.providers.sftp'"

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to copy files from SFTP to google cloud storage.

- Composer version = 1.16.12
- Airflow version = 1.10.15.

While executing getting exception `No module named 'airflow.providers.sftp'`.
Much appreciated if some one can give pointers.

Code snippet is :

```
import os
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators import python_operator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.sftp_to_gcs import SFTPToGCSOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


with models.DAG("test_ssh_to_gcs", start_date=days_ago(1), schedule_interval=None) as dag:

    copy_file_from_ssh_to_gcs = SFTPToGCSOperator(
        task_id="file-copy-ssh-to-gcs",
        source_path="/ ",
        destination_bucket='test_sftp_to_gcs',
        destination_path="test/test.csv",
        gcp_conn_id="google_cloud_default",
        sftp_conn_id="sftp_test",
    )

copy_file_from_ssh_to_gcs
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

First, have you tried installing the [package](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-sftp/) with `pip install apache-airflow-providers-sftp` ?
Be also careful about the documentation version you are refering to. With Airflow 2.0, some packages have been [moved](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/backport-providers.html).

Answer (score 1):

Install dependency via pip.

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-sftp
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because SFTPToGCSOperator uses `airflow.providers.sftp.operators.SFTPOperator` under the hood, which present in airflow >= 2.0.0.

The bad news is need to upgrade your Airflow version to use `airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.sftp_to_gcs.SFTPToGCSOperator`.

If you don't want / cannot upgrade airflow, you can create a DAG chaining two operators:

| Operator | Airflow 1.x import |
| --- | --- |
| SFTP Operator (download a file to a local using 'operation=get') | `from airflow.contrib.operators.sftp_operator import SFTPOperator` |
| Upload File to Google cloud storage | `from airflow.contrib.operators.file_to_gcs import FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` |

This should do the trick:

```py
LOCALFILE = '/tmp/kk'

with models.DAG("test_ssh_to_gcs", start_date=days_ago(1), schedule_interval=None) as dag:

   download_sftp = SFTPOperator(
      task_id = 'part1_sftp_download_to_local',
      ssh_conn_id="sftp_test",
      local_file=LOCALFILE,
      remote_file='',
      operation='get')

   gcp_upload = FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
      task_id='part2_upload_to_gcs',
      bucket='test_sftp_to_gcs',
      src=LOCALFILE,
      dst="test/test.csv",
      google_cloud_storage_conn_id="google_cloud_default" # configured in Airflow
   ) 

   sftp_download >> gcp_upload
```

Answer (score 0):

With airflow 1.10 you can install [backported packages](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-google/)

For your case the following need to be added to your composer cluster:

1- apache-airflow-backport-providers-google

2- apache-airflow-backport-providers-sftp

3- apache-airflow-backport-providers-ssh