# GCP Composer - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.sftp'

Tags: sftp, google-cloud-composer, modulenotfounderror

I trying to getting data from FTP server's txt file by GCP Composer Tasks.

So I imported `SFTPOperator` package in code.

but error occurred:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.sftp'
```

then, I tried few ways:

- [Getting exception "No module named 'airflow.providers.sftp'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68754558/getting-exception-no-module-named-airflow-providers-sftp)
- Install `apache-airflow-providers-sftp` by composer pypi packages

but didn't work.

My GCP Composer Environment is as below:

- Image Version : composer-1.17.7-airflow-2.1.4
- python version : 3
- Network VPC-native : Enable

How can I use `SFTPOperator` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will have to install sftp package, `pip install 'apache-airflow[sftp]'`  . You can check the [built-in and extras packages](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/extra-packages-ref.html) that airflow components have when installed (varies from version).

Once you have it installed you should be able to use [SFTPOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-sftp/stable/_api/airflow/providers/sftp/operators/sftp/index.html) by importing the operator inside your DAG.

```
from airflow.providers.sftp.operators.sftp import SFTPOperation,SFTPOperator

with DAG(...) as dag:

   upload_op = SFTPOperator(
    task_id="test_sftp",
    ssh_conn_id="ssh_default",
    local_filepath="/tmp/file.txt",
    remote_filepath="/tmp/tmp1/tmp2/file.txt",
    operation=SFTPOperation.GET, 
    dag=dag
   )

   ...
```

You can also find a mock tests on the airflow git hub project that can provide you some guidance, check this [link](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/tests/providers/sftp/operators/test_sftp.py).

**UPDATE 17/08/2022:** As commented by Diana, Composer has a documented way to install its components as mention on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-private). Be advised to pick up the composer version your project uses as there is version1 and version2 guides.

Comment: Hello @박현균, did this answered your question?

Comment: I agree with all of this except the way you say a package can be installed. Locally you'd do a `pip install` command but for composer you'll need to install packages as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-private

Comment: Agree! I have updated the response with it, I got confused with the instructions within apache airflow/composer. Much appreciated Diana.